# WP 8.1 MVVM light cannot instantiate constructor

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light

I have implemented the navigation service and the view model locator. I can open  my page using OnNavigatedTo correctly. But when the page initializes, it does not go through any of the constructors declared.

My implementation of the locator

```
INavigationService navigationService = new NavigationService();
navigationService.Configure("About", typeof(AboutPage));
return navigationService;

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
INavigationService navigationService = CreateNavigationService();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
```

The constructor on my Page

```
public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;  
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: I wonder if an instance of the view model is even injected into the page itself?

Comment: How does this affect the problem?

Comment: The viewModel is a dependency of the view. If the view does not somehow require the viewModel (usually a constructor dependency), the IoC will never instantiate the viewModel itself. I do assume the constructor of the viewModel is the problem, as this is shown in your question.

Comment: Ok, i got also a parameter-less constructor but doesnt change the result. so the question is: which constructor is using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing it as argument of your constructor, you can use the following to retrieve the navigation service:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _navigationService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
}
```

The action of registering does not create any instance yet; the instantiation is on demand.
You can find details on the MVVM Light IOC class in this MSDN article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/jj991965.aspx